# Jython for Java with TextBlob

Tags: java, ascii, jython, textblob

I am currently working on a Java project with python integration.
For that purpose I am using the following packages and ide:

Eclipse luna
Jython 2.7.0
TextBlob v0.10.0-dev

Here is my java code-snippet:

```
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile("AnSoMiaPy/analyser/test1.py");
        PyObject translated_text = interpreter.get("translated_text");
        interpreter.close();
        System.out.println("translated_text: " + translated_text.toString());
```

The python code is also fairly simply.

```
        #!/usr/bin/python
        # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
        from textblob import TextBlob
        import sys
        reload(sys)
        sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

        text = '''
        The titular threat of The Blob has always struck me as the ultimate             movie
        monster: an insatiably hungry, amoeba-like mass able to penetrate
        virtually any safeguard, capable of--as a doomed doctor chillingly
        describes it--"assimilating flesh on contact.
        Snide comparisons to gelatin be damned, it's a concept with the most
        devastating of potential consequences, not unlike the grey goo scenario
        proposed by technological theorists fearful of
        artificial intelligence run rampant.
        '''
        blob = TextBlob(text)
        blob.noun_phrases   # WordList(['titular threat', 'blob',
                #            'ultimate movie monster',
                #            'amoeba-like mass', ...])

        for sentence in blob.sentences:
        print(sentence.sentiment.polarity)
        # 0.060
        # -0.341

        translated_text = blob.translate(to="de")
        print(translated_text)
        print blob.sentiment.polarity
```

When I am executing the python code I get what I expect:

> 0.06
>   -0.341666666667
>   Der Titular Bedrohung des BLOB hat mich als die ultimative Film immer geschlagen
>   Monster: ein unersättlich hungrig, amöbenartige Masse in der Lage, zu durchdringen
>   praktisch jede Sicherung, in der Lage ist - als Untergang geweihten Arzt unterkühlt
>   es beschreibt - "assimilieren Fleisch auf Kontakt.
>   Abfällige Vergleiche zu Gelatine verdammt sein, es ist ein Konzept, mit dem die meisten
>   verheerende der möglichen Folgen, nicht anders als die graue Schmiere-Szenario
>   durch technologische Theoretiker fürchten vorgeschlagen
>   künstliche Intelligenz wuchern.
>   -0.159090909091

However, when I call the python-script with jython I am getting the following result:

> 0.0
>   0.0
>   Der Titular Bedrohung des BLOB hat mich als die ultimative Film immer geschlagen
>   Monster: ein unersättlich hungrig, amöbenartige Masse in der Lage, zu durchdringen
>   praktisch jede Sicherung, in der Lage ist - als Untergang geweihten Arzt unterkühlt
>   es beschreibt - "assimilieren Fleisch auf Kontakt.
>   Abfällige Vergleiche zu Gelatine verdammt sein, es ist ein Konzept, mit dem die meisten
>   verheerende der möglichen Folgen, nicht anders als die graue Schmiere-Szenario
>   durch technologische Theoretiker fürchten vorgeschlagen
>   künstliche Intelligenz wuchern.
>   0.0
>   translated_text: TextBlob("Der Titular Bedrohung des BLOB hat mich als die ultimative Film immer geschlagen
>   Monster: ein unersÃ¤ttlich hungrig, amÃ¶benartige Masse in der Lage, zu durchdringen
>   praktisch jede Sicherung, in der Lage ist - als Untergang geweihten Arzt unterkÃ¼hlt
>   es beschreibt - "assimilieren Fleisch auf Kontakt.
>   AbfÃ¤llige Vergleiche zu Gelatine verdammt sein, es ist ein Konzept, mit dem die meisten
>   verheerende der mÃ¶glichen Folgen, nicht anders als die graue Schmiere-Szenario
>   durch technologische Theoretiker fÃ¼rchten vorgeschlagen
>   kÃ¼nstliche Intelligenz wuchern.")

The sentiment.polarity is suddenly 0 and after accessing the translated variable in java and printing it the ascii encoding looks a bit weird.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?